# Process.Kill() vs Process.Start("taskkill",...)

Tags: c#, process

I've a small C# installer application and I want to kill a process. Are there any advantages / differences in using

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("[taskname]");
foreach (Process p in procs) { p.Kill(); }
```

vs

```
Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM [taskname].exe");
```

I read somewhere that using "taskkill" is only available in XP(and up), so would that make `Process.Kill()` the safer option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Process.Kill` is prefered, because you are not starting another process as you do, when you start `taskkill` to kill the process. It is just a lot of useless overhead.

Comment: Taskkill seems to be more reliable on killing processes when you try to kill explorer.exe for example.

Answer (score 27):

p.kill() doesn't kill the process tree.

So taskkill is needed if you want to kill the whole process tree.